# Materialize Icons doesn't work in JavaFX Browser

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine, google-material-icons, webengine

I'm trying to show [MaterialIcons](https://material.io/icons/) on my JavaFx WebBrowser using webEngine, but it just shows the description of the icon. Icons doesn't work also on IE and Safari. Does anyone know how to make it readable?

Comment: I tried a quick test, and it seems to work using numerical character references, but not using ligatures.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it work with ligatures? I have a lot of Icons in my website..

Answer (score 0):

I also struggle on that one, so for those who are intersted to know, JavaFX is only compatible with MaterialIcons written with numerical character references as James_D stated and not with ligatures format.

So insted of writing : `<i class="material-icons">add</i>`
You should write : `<i class="material-icons">&#xE145;</i>`

Here is cheatsheet link for converting Material Icon ligatures to their respective numerical character reference : https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints